# Python3 work effectively with remote binary data

Tags: python-3.x, io, sftp, paramiko

I have some remote devices that are accessed via sftp using paramiko over (usually) a cellular connection. I need to do two things to some binary files on them:

1. Read them byte-by-byte to enter the contents into a database
2. Write the entire file out to a networked drive.

I have code to do each of these things that works, but I need to do *both* things in the most reasonably efficient way.

I could pass around the file_handle, read byte by byte to do the database entry, then do `file_handle.seek(0)` and pass that to `other_file_handle.write`, but I'm a little concerned about the flakiness of the cellular connection as I'm reading remote files byte by byte and processing the results and it means effectively iterating the thing twice.

I could fix the double iteration part of that problem by both translating the bytes to meaningful data and simultaneously writing them to a buffer to later dump to disk, but that seems awfully...manual?

I could read the entire remote binary file, write it to disk, open that for byte-by-byte processing but that's really inefficient compared to doing all the work in memory.

I could read in the remote data to an IO stream, and then manually both convert bytes and also put them into a write stream. But then the file writing code is totally coupled to the parsing code and again it's a lot of lower level manipulation.

The last is probably the "best" way but I'm hoping there's a better higher-level abstraction to use that lets me maintain a better separation of concerns. Is there an equivalent of the posix `tee` command or something here?

Comment: Are you aware of ``itertools.tee``?

Comment: I am now thanks. That should work I can pass it the file handle directly and get independent streams. Put in an answer and I'll accept.